# Add a cursor/icon in OpenLayers to mark precisely

Tags: openlayers, mobile

We are using OpenLayers in a mobile application developed in Ionic. When we trace any feature (Point/Line/Polygon) by using finger precision is not accurate and user is not able to exactly mark the specific point.

Is there any way that we can add icon (plus/cross) and adjust the point to the center of the icon, Now if user tap finger within a tolerance range then the point at the center of the icon is considered.

Comment: Yes, there are ways. See example of custom interaction: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.html. In your case icon could be your plus icon. When on the right place you could double tap it to place polygon point on desired place, which would require some programing of course.